# Predict new text using Python Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) model

Tags: python, predict, lda, topic-modeling

I use [LDA](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda) package to model topics with a large set of text documents. A simplified(!) example (I removed all other cleaning steps, lemmatization, biograms etc.) of my code is below and I'm happy with the results so far. But now I struggle to write a code to predict a new text. I can't find any reference in LDA's documentation about save/loading/predict options. I can add a new text to my set and fit it again but it is an expensive way of doing it.

I know I can do it with gensim. But somehow the results from the gensim model are less impressive so I'd stick to my initial LDA model.

Will appreciate any suggestions!

My code:

```
import lda
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))  # nltk stopwords list

documents = ["Liz Dawn: Coronation Street's Vera Duckworth dies at 77",
            'Game of Thrones stars Kit Harington and Rose Leslie to wed',
            'Tony Booth: Till Death Us Do Part actor dies at 85',
            'The Child in Time: Mixed reaction to Benedict Cumberbatch drama',
            "Alanna Baker: The Cirque du Soleil star who 'ran off with the circus'",
            'How long can The Apprentice keep going?',
            'Strictly Come Dancing beats X Factor for Saturday viewers',
            "Joe Sugg: 8 things to know about one of YouTube's biggest stars",
            'Sir Terry Wogan named greatest BBC radio presenter',
            "DJs celebrate 50 years of Radio 1 and 2'"]

clean_docs = []
for doc in documents:
    # set all to lower case and tokenize
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(doc.lower())
    # remove stop words
    texts = [i for i in tokens if i not in stops]
    clean_docs.append(texts)

# join back all tokens to create a list of docs
docs_vect = [' '.join(txt) for txt in clean_docs]

cvectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=10000, stop_words=stops)
cvz = cvectorizer.fit_transform(docs_vect)

n_topics = 3
n_iter = 2000
lda_model = lda.LDA(n_topics=n_topics, n_iter=n_iter)
X_topics = lda_model.fit_transform(cvz)

n_top_words = 3
topic_summaries = []

topic_word = lda_model.topic_word_  # get the topic words
vocab = cvectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i, topic_dist in enumerate(topic_word):
    topic_words = np.array(vocab)[np.argsort(topic_dist)][:-(n_top_words+1):-1]
    topic_summaries.append(' '.join(topic_words))
    print('Topic {}: {}'.format(i+1, ' '.join(topic_words)))

# How to predict a new document?
new_text = '50 facts about Radio 1 & 2 as they turn 50'
```

Comment: Is your use of `fit`/`fit_transform` on `lda_model` correct? The docs (http://pythonhosted.org/lda/api.html#lda.lda.LDA.fit_transform) suggest that `fit` is for training data and `fit_transform` or `transform` is for test data.

Comment: Yeah, I read about this and some people suggest that you can use `fit_transform` to get topics quicker... I tried using both and it gives me the same results.

Comment: @aviss did you fix the problem?

Comment: @user3778289 This package is very basic and doesn't have a variety of options as gensim or mallet. I switched to gensim and played with hyper-parameters to improve the results. With gensim you can save/load the model and feed new documents etc.

Comment: @aviss thank you for replying. actually i am also doing this but my results with gensim are not very good